oracle create table from existing table with primary key of existing table
In oracle I would like to create table from existing table with the primary key of the existing table. I know I can create people1 then alter people1 to have the primary key. Is there a way to modify create table people1 as (select * from people); to have id int primary key as the primary key?
CREATE TABLE people(
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(55),
  status int,
  phone varchar(55)
);

INSERT INTO people VALUES
(1, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'),
(2, 'John', 1, '214-444-1234'),
(3, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'),
(4, 'Mary', 0, '555-111-1234'),
(5, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'),
(6, 'Jeff', 0, '214-222-1234'),
(7, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'),
(8, 'Bill', 1, '817-333-1234'),
(9, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234'),
(10, 'Bob' , 1, '214-555-1234');

create table people1 as (select * from people);

ALTER TABLE people1
ADD CONSTRAINT people1_pk PRIMARY KEY (id);

https://dbfiddle.uk/cEiJ2ZqF

Put the constraint in the list of column identifiers:
CREATE TABLE people1(id PRIMARY KEY, name, status, phone) AS
SELECT id, name, status, phone FROM people;

or, for a named constraint:
CREATE TABLE people1(
  id CONSTRAINT people1__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  name,
  status,
  phone
) AS
SELECT id, name, status, phone FROM people;

fiddle

use CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ... to create the table with the same schema, then populate it.
CREATE TABLE people1 LIKE people;

INSERT INTO people1
SELECT * FROM people;


This gives the error ORA-00922: missing or invalid option fiddle. The documentation you link to is for MySQL and not Oracle.

Sorry, I googled oracle but it returned a mysql match and I didn't notice.
